# Is there any way to find out what nth, a specific character is on a string?

Tags: python, string

For example, finding nth the `a` in the string `abcdefg`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think `find()` is what you are looking for.

```
example = "abcdefg"
print(example.find("a"))
```

This should return 0.